# Unable to get available audio device from Lync 2013 sdk

Tags: c#, lync, lync-client-sdk, lync-2013

When I try to get the list of available audio devices like this.

```
LyncClient client = LyncClient.GetClient();
foreach (Device dev in client.DeviceManager.AudioDevices)
{
      //Do something
}
```

I get the error `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

```
"Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 
'Microsoft.Office.Uc.IAudioDevice2'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface 
call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{86B3E5FE-4635-4C1E-
A725-C80B71D04984}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported 
(Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE))."
```

Here is the stack trace

```
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
at Microsoft.Lync.Model.Internal.UCWCache.CreateUCW(Object source, CCOMInfo ccomInfo)
at Microsoft.Lync.Model.Internal.UCWCache.GetITTargetNS(Object source)
at Microsoft.Lync.Model.Internal.UCEnumerator`2.get_Current()
at Microsoft.Lync.Model.Internal.UCEnumerator`2.System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<S>.get_Current()
```

And the inner exception stack trace

```
at Microsoft.Lync.Model.Device.AudioDevice.INTERNAL_Init(IAudioDevice initInterface)
at Microsoft.Lync.Model.Device.AudioDevice.INTERNAL_Init_Object(Object initInterface)
```

Comment: i have the same issue, can you please post the version that solved this issue (both sdk and Lync Client 2013).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I use this version of Lync http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2825630. and this version of the sdk http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/confirmation.aspx?id=36824

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check that both Lync and your SDK have the same version numbers?

There seems to be many releases of Lync 2013, and they may not have the same version.

Answer (score 0):

Problem appears to be in the "//Do something" part of the code.

I just ran he following fine.

```
 var Client = LyncClient.GetClient();

       foreach (var dev in Client.DeviceManager.AudioDevices)
       {               
           Console.WriteLine(dev.Name);
       }
```

Any chance of a stack  trace if this doesn't work?

Comment: The error happen within the foreach itself when it try to affect the dev variable. I added the stack trace.